# Emulate method call on heap in C++?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Although heap memory is allocated slower than the thread call stack, it is considerably larger, allowing room for a much larger number of operations (such as massively-recursive method calls) to be performed. Although the stack can be resized, the values allowed are still comparatively minuscule (a few MBs available) relative to the heap (more than 1 GB available).

Out of curiosity, in C++ (as an example), is it possible to emulate calling a method by using the heap instead of the thread call stack?

Comment: What is the limitation of the stack size ? What compiler ?

Comment: It is always possible to derecursivate code by emulating the stack with an array, but this requires a complete rewrite.

Comment: Linux (and prob most Unix-like systems) allow you to set arbitrarily large maximum stack sizes (it's an OS-level setting, via ulimit or similar).

Comment: Simple Answer: No.

Comment: Since neither C nor C++ actually have a *notion* of either stack or heap, just "automatic" vs. "dynamically allocated" storage, the answer would be "not in a portable way". And not without massive help by the OS. ;-)

Comment: You'd need to convert the method calls to some sort of continuation passing style ... or better called "continuation returning style" ... in order to prevent pilling up data on the stack. You won't be able to work without at least a bit of stack, though.

Comment: yes, it's perfectly possible. build a function object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (contrived and probably overcomplicated) implementation of factorial that uses only the heap:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <typeinfo>

struct factorial
{
    struct call_concept
    {
        virtual int operator()() const = 0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<call_concept> generate_next() const = 0;
        virtual ~call_concept() = default;
    };

    static std::unique_ptr<call_concept> generate_term(int i);

    struct terminator : call_concept
    {
        int operator()() const override { return 1; }
        std::unique_ptr<call_concept> generate_next() const override { return nullptr; }
    };

    struct fact_term : call_concept
    {
        fact_term(int i) : _i(i) {};
        int operator()() const override { return _i; }
        std::unique_ptr<call_concept> generate_next() const override {
            return generate_term(_i - 1);
        }
        int _i;
    };


    struct call
    {
        call(std::unique_ptr<call_concept> pc) : _impl(std::move(pc)) {}

        int operator()() const {
            return _impl->operator()();
        }

        int operator*(const call& r) const {
            return (*this)() * r();
        }

        std::unique_ptr<call_concept> _impl;
    };

    friend int operator*(int i, const call& r) {
        return i * r();
    }



    int operator()(int i) {

        auto pt = generate_term(i);
        std::vector<call> stack;

        while (pt) {
            auto next_term = pt->generate_next();
            stack.emplace_back(std::move(pt));
            pt = std::move(next_term);
        }

        return std::accumulate(std::begin(stack), end(stack), 1, std::multiplies<>());
    }
};

auto factorial::generate_term(int i) -> std::unique_ptr<call_concept>
{
    if (i > 1) {
        return std::make_unique<fact_term>(i);
    }
    else {
        return std::make_unique<terminator>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto i = factorial()(10);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
3628800
```

Comment: Thanks for a concrete example :)